# How to get visual studio to forget about an old tfs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We moved to a new tfs, with a new name, the old one doesn't exist anymore.
When I create a new blank solution and select file|source control|change source control and click on 'Bind' Visual Studio tries to connect to the old tfs.

Under Team|Connect to tfs|.servers I removed the old one and connected to the new one *only*.
Also my workspace is mapped to the new server *only*.

I cannot understand where Visual Studio stores the old tfs or how to destroy it's memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to delete your workspace as explained here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx

Comment: In [profile]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0 I deleted the Cache folder including a config file that stored the old name. Then 'Add to source control' worked. 'Bind' under 'change source control' didn't work because there was no mapping found.